# Can I somehow make get requests to Booqable API without timing out?

Tags: python, python-requests

Booqable have a public facing REST api (api key needed) - https://developers.booqable.com/#introduction

There are several relevant endpoints.

If I wanna get all the orders I use the 'List all orders' end point. This is an example.

`curl --request GET \  --url 'https://example.booqable.com/api/1/orders'`

The json get back has all the orders but it is missing some entries. One of those would be 'Planning' which is also an endpoint.

If I instead take one of the order ids from the json with all the others and use a different endpoint that fetches orders individually I get much more data. And it also includes planning that I need.

When I use the all orders endpoint I get all the orders - no problems. If I try and make +700 get calls to the single order endpoint, using the order ids from all the other orders, the connection to Booqable times out.

Now I understand that they are protecting their server/API from attacks and what not. It just doesn't seem like that many requests. But correct if I'm mistaken on that point.

Can anyone tell me if there is some smart way around this?

Comment: The `requests` package with help from the `urllib3` package can set a backoff but I would start with a `time.sleep(1)` inbetween requests. If you still run into problems up it to `10` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly extract about 2,000 records OK using that same endpoint but what I have to do is only get them 100 at a time & put a 200msec delay between each call.  Takes about 45 seconds to download them.

As for your question about not being able to access certain fields. I suspect they are buried a couple of layers deep in the JSON if that makes sense.

I created this super useful report in Google Sheets that uses App Script.  I'm not sure if it includes fields you're after.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlFXJ.png)

Comment: Man, thanks. Right now I'm doing 0.5 sec timeout's but the whole thing takes about 8 minutes to download. It's not ideal. I haven't tried your solution yet but I'm sure this will solve my problem. I'll get back when I've tried it.

Comment: I don't think we are talking about the same end point. I'm talking about getting individual orders being different from getting all the orders at once. When I get all the orders I can do 1000 at a time and goes really quick. When I wanna get ALL the data associated with an individual order, as specified by the Booqable API, I use the get individual order end point using the order number for the individual order. This gives me more data than if I ask for all the orders at once. Each of the individual orders are then missing data, i.e. the "plannings" field, in the .json returned.